# Is it safe to use branch mainnet-pack-validator?

Tags: node, archive-node

For reference, Pierre from the dev team said that:

> A [branch mainnet-pack-validator](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/commits/mainnet-pack-validator) has just been pushed to the gitlab
>   repo tezos/tezos. This branch changes the way the chain is stored on
>   the disk (dividing the size by an order of magnitude!). It requires,
>   as a consequence to restart from a freshly imported snapshot (or to
>   resync the chain from scratch (with --history-mode archive if you need
>   it)). We are also not sure this is fully ready yet from critical
>   infrastructures but this looks super promissing. If you launch the
>   tezos-node with newly introduced option --multiprocess, in addition of
>   the gain in size of the chain on disk, the "validation" of block is
>   done by an independant process independently of the action of
>   answering to the peers and the RPC of the node. This should imply a
>   complete goodbye to freezes of the node... In one word, use with care
>   but feelthe taste of the future (and report issues)!

Is it safe to use this branch for a production node with the purpose of reducing disk usage?